# What is the first parameter of curl_easy_escape for?

Tags: c, libcurl, urlencode

The `curl_easy_escape` function of curl takes a `CURL*` as its first parameter, as [curl’s documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) indicates:

```
char *curl_easy_escape(CURL *curl, const char *string, int length);
                           ↑
```

I don’t understand what this parameter is used for, since escaping a URL shouldn’t need a curl handle. In fact, curl’s source code [ignores this parameter](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/d56270cb308e14dbba6525118f6ad96e1bec2819/lib/escape.c#L83).

Is it safe to simply use `NULL` for this parameter if I need to escape an URL without having a curl handle beforehand, as [the implementation of `curl_escape`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/d56270cb308e14dbba6525118f6ad96e1bec2819/lib/escape.c#L69) does?

Comment: It's hard to guess the developers' intention, but they could plan to use `curl` in a future version. So to be safe I wouldn't pass NULL even if it obviously works at the moment

Comment: Thge documentation doesn't explicitely mention the `curl` parameter, but if in doubt, provide a valid `CURL*`. You have got one anyway, so just pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for backward ABI compatibility. `CURL *curl` was used 6 years ago: [curl_easy_escape](https://github.com/curl/curl/blame/434f8d0389f2969b393ff81ead713b7600502f27/lib/escape.c#L115), [Curl_convert_to_network](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/434f8d0389f2969b393ff81ead713b7600502f27/lib/non-ascii.c#L82).

It was always and is now safe to pass `NULL`: [curl_escape](https://github.com/curl/curl/blame/master/lib/escape.c#L69), [curl_easy_escape](https://github.com/curl/curl/blame/master/lib/escape.c#L83).

The history is interesting. `char *curl_unescape(const char *string, int length)` was the first function. Later `char *curl_easy_escape(CURL *handle, const char *string, int inlength)` was introduced for supporting all extended ASCII charsets with help of `iconv`. And finally `curl_easy_escape` code was almost rollbacked to `curl_unescape` and stopped using `CURL *handle`.